# Making PHP cookies stay on after browser in closed

Tags: php, cookies

A user is automatically logged out of my site upon closing the browser.

Is there a way to make cookies stay active after the browser is closed?

Comment: Cookies do remain when the browser is closed.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
setcookie("test", "test", time()+3600);
?>
```

Just set the time on it to expire in the future.

Comment: Okay... in Chrome, I see something called `PHPSESSID`.  Is there a way I can make this last beyond closing the browser?

Answer (score 1):

You need to manualy set the cookies to keep the session. You need a manualy computed session to identify the user when he opens the browser again.